# Java: Reading and Writing multiple arrays selectively to a single file

Tags: java, android, arrays, file

I know this question have been asked and answered here before, but mine is a special case which I did not find an answer to yet.

I have between 100,000 and a Million arrays of type `int` with a 'fixed' length of 32^3, I need to store those arrays in a single file without the need to iterate over them.
I know it is possible with [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html), I have even found how to write multiple objects to a single file and read them back (which might sound like it solves my problem) but no, it doesn't.

My actual problem is that I need to add/update a single array to that file, and read a single array as well.The whole arrays might have maximum of 10 arrays that were modified in a second, so I will need to write the changes down to that file without the need to rewrite the whole file as this is way to slow and inefficient.

So my question: is it possible to save a fixed length `int` array to a file containing many `int` arrays of the same length? and read a specific `int` array from that file? without having to iterate through each array on reading or writing?

Comment: That gives 12.8GB - 128GB of memory, are you sure you gave the correct numbers?

Comment: You can try a different approach for that. You can create a copy in memory and write that in file... than do all add update operation from in memory arrays... and write one scheduler job for that .. lets say after every 10 min .. it will create new thread to write a bunch of arrays to file. it will fast your add update execution speed.

Comment: Don't use `ObjectOutputStream` - as all int[] are of the same length you can you can convert them to byte[] and then write them one after another.

Comment: @ekaerovets: 95% of the data have less than 100 arrays, some files have 1 array, others 100, but the rest 5% have up to 1m arrays. I don't care for the size for now. i care more about the ability to be able to write a single array to that huge file in less than 100ms.

Comment: Nirav, The memory will not be able to handle such amount of data

Comment: @Robert woudln't this require me to iterate through the array?

Comment: Just computer the offset and jump to it. No need for iterating anything.

Comment: I mean "Convert them to byte" dosen't require iterating over them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RandomAccessFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

If your arrays are of fixed length, then you may consider a RandomAccessFile as a large arrays and calculate position as index_of_array_you_need * array_size + index_of_the_element_in_array

Your array size will be 32768*4 bytes, so if you need to update the number in the 3rd array at position 100, you should fetch 4 bytes from RandomAccessFile by address 2 * 32768 * 4 + 100 * 4

Comment: And reading/writing to this file wouldnt require me to iterate through the arrays?

Comment: All of your arrays are of a fixed size. Therefore you can calculate the starting offset within the file as ekaerovets pointed out.

Comment: The reason why i am having fixed length is because of this, the actually array might be half full, but I know the maximum limit for it this is why i said it is fixed length, because i know it will be faster to find that array in the file. but my question is, once i read the data from the file, will i need to iterate through it to assign it to the `int x = new int[32768];` ?

Comment: @RonanDejhero no, you don't have to read the whole file, only the portion of it you need. BTW, not int x = new int[32768], but int[] x = ...

Comment: @ekaerovets thanks i got that, but my question would be about the data I read from the file, will i need to iterate through it to assign it to the variable?